# Scroll up in mongo console on Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, console-application

I need to see output of db.currentOp() in my mongo console (mongo.exe) on Windows. But it gives so much results that they don't fit the screen. If I scroll up with the scrollbar on the left, I still can't get entire output. Is there a way to see the entire output?

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to [increase the Screen Buffer Size](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/13919-windows-7-increase-the-buffer-size-of-the-command-prompt) in your Windows Command Prompt settings.